# pl sql with result merge together issue

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my pl sql query and result.

```
    with
   tblObject (profile_value,profile_entry) as
     (select  profile_value,profile_entry
         FROM 
        table1'
     ),
   tblObjecttemp as
     (select regexp_substr(profile_value, '\|([^|]+)\|' , 1, column_value) val,
             column_value cv,
             profile_value,
             profile_entry
      from tblObject cross join
        table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                            connect by level <= regexp_count(profile_value, '\|') + 1
                           ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
    )
    
  select 'dro.LU_NAME=' || '''' || profile_entry ||  '''' || ' and dro.KEY_REF=' ||  '''' || listagg(REGEXP_REPLACE(val,'[|]',''), '''' ||' or dro.KEY_REF=''') within group (order by cv) result  
   from tblObjecttemp 
  group by profile_entry;
```

[image]

```
dro.LU_NAME='ActiveSeparate' and dro.KEY_REF='WO_NO=1^' or dro.KEY_REF='WO_NO=600003^'
dro.LU_NAME='Analysis' and dro.KEY_REF='ANALYSIS_NO=4^
```

Now I need to add all rows together with 'or'. I tried using listagg inside listagg again. But its getting errors. Is there any easy way to this. please help.

Comment: Please provide sample data in text format to reproduce your result

Comment: @astentx
 I have updated the question with text data. please check

Comment: "It is getting errors" isn't very descriptive. You didn't post code that raises those errors. You didn't say which errors you got. We don't have any sample data to work with. So, what kind of assistance do you expect?

Comment: I have found it myself. thanks for considerations

Answer (score 0):

I have found it my self:

```
 select listagg('dro.LU_NAME=' || '''' || profile_entry ||  '''' || ' and dro.KEY_REF=' ||  '''' || listagg(REGEXP_REPLACE(val,'[|]',''), '''' ||' or dro.KEY_REF=''') within group (order by cv),' or ')within group (order by profile_entry) result  
   from tblObjecttemp 
  group by profile_entry;
```